# Im forcing to use getElementsByClassName()[] rather than getElementByClass()

Tags: javascript

I have 8 `divs` with **id="div1","div2","div3"....** and a **class=divs**. I also have a `button` with **class="div1","div2","div3".....**.

When I click the `button` with **id="div1"**, it will first remove all the **class="selected"** to all `div` that has a **class="divs"** then only the `div` with **id="div1"** will have the `class` **selected**. And so on.....

I want to use `document.getElementByClass()` for removing `class` but it don't work in my **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/q98bLtcx/1/)**. :(

Instead, Im forced to use `document.getElementsByClassName()[]`. But it seems so hard to code since it requires me to put the specific arrays for the `classname`.

This is exactly I want to achieve **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/q98bLtcx/)**

Comment: `document.getElementByClass`?

Comment: There is no such method in javascript like getElementByClass
There is a method getElementByClassName which returns an array of elements those have that class name

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no `getElementByClass` for a reason: unlike `id`, `class` is not specified to be unique in a document. Which element would you get? No, you need the ability to get all of them. And if you get an array, that's solved by looping, not by repeating rows for each index:

However, your design is inefficient; and if you're already using jQuery, you can write it very tightly. This would be better:

```
<button class="divbuttons" data-div="div1">div1</button>
<button class="divbuttons" data-div="div2">div2</button>
...
```

then you can:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.divbuttons').click(function() {
    var div = $(this).data("div");
    $('.divs.selected').removeClass('selected');
    $('#' + div).addClass('selected');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

This is an easy one. There is no `document.getElementByClass`

You have `document.getElementById` or `document.getElementByClassName`

Comment: Of, perhaps even better, `document.querySelectorAll()`.

Answer (score 2):

There's no such thing as getElementByClass() because multiple elements can have the same class. There's getElementById() (elements have unique ids, or at least they're supposed to) and getElementsByClassName(), which returns an array of all elements that match the class specified.

Comment: Isn't this a comment?

Answer (score 1):

try

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("button[class^=div]").click(function () {

        $(".divs.selected").removeClass("selected");

        $("#" + $(this).attr("class")).addClass("selected");

    });
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/q98bLtcx/2/)